# fetching data from store in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I am making a project in which I have a JSON server (having id, feature, description in it) running back and I have used saga, store to fetch the items after fetching the items on the page.js ... now I want to do is when I click on the feature(fetched data from JSON) then it should show me the description to that feature (description and feature both are available in the JSON). Can someone help

Code below:

.js code

```
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(getFeatrure())

 }, [dispatch])

 const feature = useSelector(state => state.feature.feature)
 const descHandler = () => {
    dispatch(getFeatrure())
}

 return (
    <div>
       <ul>
         {feature ? feature.map((list) => 
            {return(
                <li key={list.id}>
                    <a onClick={descHandler}>
                        {list.Features}
                    </a>
                </li>
                )
            })
        :''
        }
      </ul>
   </div>
     )
   }
```

Now above when I click feature then it should give me its specific description.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be caused by a typo `getFeatrure` -> `getFeature`?

In addition to fixing that typo, here's a shorter version of your code that should render your `ul` only if `feature` is set:

```
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(getFeature())

 }, [dispatch])

 const {feature} = useSelector(state => state.feature)
 const descHandler = () => {
    dispatch(getFeature())
}

return (
  <div>
    {feature && (
      <ul>
        {feature.map((list) => (
          <li key={list.id}>
            <a onClick={descHandler}>{list.Features}</a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    )}
  </div>
)
```

I also think you should change your naming convention for:

- `feature &&...feature.map((list) =>...` to `features &&...features.map((feature)=>...`
- `list.Features`, Features should be lowercase and singular since each `a` should have one clickable feature. (unless I misunderstood)

May I have a look at your reducer if the above didn't fix it?

Comment: Thanks for helping, it was not due to typo but because my JSON data was not stored in the redux-store. So because of that, I was facing this issue. Anyways again thanks for the help :)